# Convert a php variable to session variable

Tags: php, session-state, session-variables

I am having problem setting a variable in PHP for multiple use into `if statements`.

Although there are many files in my layout but these are the 3 files relevant to this issue:

**session.php** (it is actually a JavaScript function which determines the browser-width of the visitor which is included in my javascript file and I call this via an ajax call. However since that is irrelevant to this issue hence to avoid confusion and too much code on this page I am avoiding that file.)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['layoutType'] = $_REQUEST['layoutType'];  
?>
```

**core.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['layoutType'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var session=false; var layoutType;</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var session=true; var layoutType=' . $_SESSION['layoutType'] . ';</script>';
    }

    $layout = 'normal';

    if (!empty($_SESSION['layoutType'])) {
       $layoutType = $_SESSION['layoutType'];
       if ( $layoutType <= 219 ) {
          $layout = 'minimal';
       } else if ($layoutType >= 220 && $layoutType <= 1024 ) {
          $layout = 'small';
       } else {
          $layout = 'normal';
       }
    $_SESSION['layout'] = $layout;

    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include ('core/core.php');


// Function to load all the JavaScript files

getJS();

echo '<div>Your browser width is: ' . $_SESSION['layoutType'] . ' and Value of $layout variable currently is <strong>'.$layout.'</strong></div>'; 

if ($layout = 'normal') { ?>

    <?php echo '<strong>' . $layout . '</strong> is the value of $layout in session'; ?>

    <div id="sidebar">
    <p>Widgets go here</p>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

**The output**
[image]

Even though, The layout-width falls in the small category ***(Your browser width is: 872 and Value of $layout variable currently is small)***, it is still displaying the bit which it should display only is the layout-widthe category is normal ***(normal is the value of $layout in session)***.

Typically what is hapenning here is the value of `$layout` is being overwritten by the `if statement` in the `index.php` file.

**What I am looking for?**

Along with `layoutType` I also want the value of `$layout` to be set in the session based on the logic in `core.php`. So  that I can use it multiple times across the website in various `if statements`.

This is very important because these are varioys widgets / content in my layout which I want to load / not-load depending on the device of my visitor. Hence almost all the widhets wil be wrapped into an `if statement`.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($layout = 'normal') { ?>
```

Evaluates to true because it's an assignment (use `==` or `===` instead). You can find more information about the Comparison operators in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison).